# Recursive Sum in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: What formula to put for sum?]

Hello,

In the above example, how would I create a recursive or recursive workaround formula so that I can get the sum for the account number with multiple iterations of the account number dispersed throughout the leftmost account number column?

This is a toy example but if there were 100 unique account numbers in the right account number column with multiple iterations so ~10,000 entries in the left most account number column.

I want to do this as a formula because the data shape/size can and will change so a pivot table would not work as that needs to refreshed each time the shape changes.

I have an inkling the aggregate() function will come into play but I can't put my finger exactly on how to do it.

Does anyone have any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: =SUMIF(AllAccountNumbers,ThisAccountNumber,AllValues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMIF()` was born for this moment

---

[image]